# Unable to get Facebook User birthday

Tags: objective-c, swift, facebook

I am unable to get date of birth of user using the following code. What I am missing?

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {

        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name,birthday"])

        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            print(" result >>>>>>>>>>  \(result) ")

    })
}
```

Comment: did you authorize the user with the correct permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like this:

```
class loginViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

@IBOutlet var buttonFacebook: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.configureFacebook()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func configureFacebook()
{
    buttonFacebook.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"];
    buttonFacebook.delegate = self
    buttonFacebook.loginBehavior = .Native
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
}
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){
    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email, birthday, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){
    let loginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logOut()
}

}
```